# Analysis of proportions over time

Tags: time-series, confidence-interval, finance

My knowledge of statistics is limited and I am looking for resources to read on the matter if possible.

Anyways, I am currently trying to estimate a confidence interval for a proportion over time.  The specific example pertains to a trader's Win % as he make more trades.  My current idea is to take the first $n$ sample data to calculate a proportion, then see how that changes over the amount of trades.  I want to ultimately calculate the variability of the win %.  My confidence interval would be calculated as such:

$$p \pm \sqrt[2]{\frac{1}{n} * p(1-p)}$$

I know this is clearly the wrong approach to look into but I would appreciate it if I am pointed to in the right direction.

Comment: I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss this approach as "clearly ... wrong," especially if $np$ and $n(1-p)$ will both be large. It has a theoretical foundation, is easy to compute and interpret, may provide a meaningful envelope around the observed percentage (especially if the square root is multiplied by a suitable constant), and could function well to enhance visual or exploratory examination of the data. One avenue to pursue would be [quality-control procedures for count data.](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1268761?uid=3739864&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21104359283303)

Comment: I will more than likely use a Z-score of 80% confidence.  Thanks for the link, I will look into it.

Comment: An alternative would be to start with logistic regression, and then see if the residuals are correlated in time.